# filter Query data with from html value input

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have an HTML page with a filter that basically lists car names. When the user selects a value in the filter, I want to show the data associated to that value which comes from my PostgreSQL database. I have attached the code below. At the moment when the user is presented with the page and selects a value from the filter nothing is currently appearing not sure why. Any help welcome thank you

```
<html>
<select id="filter">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>BMW</option>
    <option>Mercedes</option>
</select>

<?php
$db_connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres");

$feild_value = $_POST["filter"];
// you can use this  $feild_value variable in query;
$result = pg_query($db_connection, "SELECT * from cars where car_name= $feild_value;");
//echo query result here
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
echo $result;
die;
?>
    
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
var value = $("#filter").val();
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
data:{"filter":value},
success:function(result){alert(result);}
})

});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Why `die();` ? As I can see, the `<script>` tag is never sent. Also, your query is open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your code but your ajax function will not work on the filter change if you didn't call it in on change even, and make sure to put a submit URL to the ajax call and I hope your PHP script is in a separate file if not your script will not run after the die()

```
$('#filter').on('change',function(e){
   //put your ajax submit here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couples of things with your code that you should be aware of.

Firstly, the `die()` function will stop the PHP code before the rest of the code is executed and outputted.
Secondly, `$result = pg_query($db_connection, "SELECT * from cars where car_name=$feild_value;");` should be
`$result = pg_query($db_connection, "SELECT * from cars where car_name='$feild_value;'");`

Note the single quote around the `$field_value` in the SQL statement.